# KKT condition in layman's term

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, intuition, convex

The most intuitive explanation for KKT condition I can find is [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255413/kkt-in-a-nutshell-graphically), which is still too complex to me. Is there any more intuitive explanation? How to introduce this to a layman?